# Ответ( ) — какой знак препинания нужен (в решённой задаче)?

Tags: пунктуация

Какой знак препинания необходим после слова "ответ" в решенной задаче: точка или двоеточие?

Comment: Фразу целиком напишите, пожалуйста. Пока не очень понятно, о чем спрашиваете.

Comment: Такой, какой учитель математики или физики скажет. Такой, как у него принято. К собственно грамматике это имеет мало отношения.

Comment: @Светлана Скажите, пожалуйста, правильно ли я поняла Ваш вопрос (с теми  "сумбурностями",  которые были) , правильно ли его отредактировала?

Comment: @Niemand с практической точки зрения согласен. Но  что по этому поводу говорят строгие правила тоже интересно.

Answer (score 2):

Я очень сомневаюсь, что Римма Михайлова правильно передала смысл вопроса, но если отвечать на него в том виде, как он стоит, то это зависит от того, что это за "ответ".

С точки зрения русского языка я бы так сформулировал.

Если "ответ" не содержит ничего, кроме цифр (обычно это бывает только в ответах к "примерам" по математике в младших классах) или цифр с указаниям величины, то нет смысла писать в два предложения.

**Ответ: 25**
или 
**Ответ: 100 м/сек**

Тут бы еще точку поставить, так как предложение закрыто, но в задачниках этим обычно пренебрегают.

Если же ответ развернутый, то нет смысла само слово "ответ" вносить в предложение.

**Ответ. Скорость первого велосипедиста 25 км/час.**
Или
**Ответ. Бородинская битва произошла 26 августа (7 сентября) 1812 года у деревни Бородино, в 125 км к западу от Москвы.**
Или
**Ответ. Слово "пароход" образовано методом словосложения из корней "пар" и "ход".**

Здесь тоже возможно двоеточие, но с точкой смотрится лучше.
Ну а если это проблема оформления домашних заданий, то тут лучше руководствоваться образцами из учебников. Ну или действительно учителя спросить. Вот правда, не знаю, что делать, если у двух учителей-предметников окажутся разные мнения...

Answer (score 2):

Помнится, мы всегда ставили двоеточие. Вот  открытый урок на фестивале: http://festival.1september.ru/articles/549243/

Здесь тоже двоеточие. Помню,раньше на госэкзаменах требовали подробную запись решения задач, видела оформление ответов, тоже с двоеточием.

С точкой как-то не встречалось, правила пунктуации допускают и тире:

Ответ - 80 км/час.

Но вернее всё-таки двоеточие, ведь  двоеточие предупреждает, что дальше последует информация.